# How to write math formulas for Rust documentation?

Tags: math, rust, documentation

I'd like to write a math formula in Rust documentation for my crate.
Looks like there is basic support of LaTeX as at least `power` works:

```
/// $ 2^8 $
```

Is rendered like:

[image]

I'd like to use a fraction in my formula, but unfortunately, this does not work:

```
/// $ \frac{x}y $
```

Comment: Could we have a feature request for that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Similar to [Steve's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24817/steve-klabnik) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46530088), using katex you could follow the approaches from:

- https://docs.rs/rustdoc-katex-demo/0.1.5/rustdoc_katex_demo/, see also the resources section. [Kernfeld](https://github.com/paulkernfeld).
- https://docs.rs/katex-doc/0.1.0/katex_doc/, [Durham](https://github.com/CAD97).

You need to put an html file in your crate in some place with the code to include with the `--html-in-header` option. Then execute:

Linux:

```
RUSTDOCFLAGS="--html-in-header path-to-your-header-file.html" cargo doc --no-deps
```

Windows cmd:

```
set RUSTDOCFLAGS=--html-in-header path-to-your-header-file.html
cargo doc --no-deps --open
```

Windows PowerShell:

```
$env:RUSTDOCFLAGS="--html-in-header .\path-to-your-header-file.html"
cargo doc --no-deps --open
```

`--no-deps` is not strictly necessary, but convenient if you do not want to add the header to the doc of another external crates.

For use in http://docs.rs you must place this on `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package.metadata.docs.rs]
rustdoc-args = [ "--html-in-header", "path-to-your-header-file.html" ]
```

The content of the header html file could be (this is the solution of [Kernfeld](https://github.com/paulkernfeld)):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-9eLZqc9ds8eNjO3TmqPeYcDj8n+Qfa4nuSiGYa6DjLNcv9BtN69ZIulL9+8CqC9Y" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.min.js"                  integrity="sha384-K3vbOmF2BtaVai+Qk37uypf7VrgBubhQreNQe9aGsz9lB63dIFiQVlJbr92dw2Lx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js"    integrity="sha384-kmZOZB5ObwgQnS/DuDg6TScgOiWWBiVt0plIRkZCmE6rDZGrEOQeHM5PcHi+nyqe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        renderMathInElement(document.body, {
            delimiters: [
                {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
                {left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false},
                {left: "$", right: "$", display: false},
                {left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

[See pwnies](https://docs.rs/pwnies/0.0.13/pwnies/) for another example (no LaTeX) of extending the possibilities of doc html pages.

**UPDATE**:

I made a [minimal example repo](https://github.com/victe/rust-latex-doc-minimal-example) showing all the above. The [crate](https://crates.io/crates/rust-latex-doc-minimal-example) with associated [documentation](https://docs.rs/rust-latex-doc-minimal-example/) using `LaTeX`.

Comment: When executing `RUSTDOCFLAGS` command on the command line I get `'RUSTDOCFLAGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, any idea why?

Comment: RUSTDOCFLAGS is not a command, is an environmental variable. If you are in Windows: with `cmd` do `set RUSTDOCFLAGS=--html-in-header src\docs-header.html` followed by `cargo doc --no-deps --open`. In `PowerShell`, set envvar with `$env:RUSTDOCFLAGS="--html-in-header .\src\docs-header.html"`.

Answer (score 6):

> Looks like there is basic support of LaTeX

Not quite. There is support for *Markdown*, not LaTeX. Stack Overflow also supports Markdown, but a different flavor. For example: `a^b` => a^b, but `a<sup>b</sup>` => a<sup>b</sup>. Markdown doesn't have support for arbitrary LaTeX. Indeed, your example:

```
/// Hi
///
/// $ 2^8 $
pub fn what() {

}
```

Generates something that still contains the `$`:

[image]

The next best thing might be to generate pre-rendered images and then include them in your documentation instead, but [an open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32104) seems to indicate that this isn't currently possible unless you are hosting the images somewhere else.

There was even [an issue to support MathJax in rustdoc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16300), but that was closed.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like Latex support was moved out: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/17390#issuecomment-61195381. As a workaround I can use also MathML, but not all browsers support it :(

Answer (score 3):

You can make it work with MathJax and `rustdoc`'s `--html-in-header` to pass in a link to the script tag it needs. This is very hacky, and won't work on docs.rs, but it can work if you host your own docs.

Answer (score 1):

I iterated on [victe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3480746/victe) minimal example and created a [crate providing a macro that embeds `.tex` in documentation as Markdown](https://crates.io/crates/include_display_mode_tex). In addition, I used newer KaTeX renderer, which makes my instructions more copy-paste friendly.

Answer (score 0):

add an alias in your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
alias cargodoc='if [ ! -f /tmp/docs-header.html ]; then curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HuangFJ/figblup/main/docs-header.html -o /tmp/docs-header.html; fi; RUSTDOCFLAGS="--html-in-header /tmp/docs-header.html" cargo doc'
```

then build docs with `cargodoc --open`.