# Is there a way to use MathJax in Rust documentation?

Tags: math, rust, rendering, documentation, equation

If I'm writing an [mdBook](https://rust-lang.github.io/mdBook/index.html), I can put:

```ini
[output.html]
mathjax-support = true
```

in my book.toml file.  Since Cargo's documentation uses mdBoook, I'd expect there's a way to add `mathjax-support` in a Cargo.toml file, but I can't find anything on this.  Does anyone know if this is a thing, and if not, where can I put in a feature request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write math formulas for Rust documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495063/how-to-write-math-formulas-for-rust-documentation)